# How to simplify slightly different if statements to one in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, flags, multiple-conditions

I would like to simplify this code and not repeat the if not statement and the print. Only one condition is being added in the first case **`curAccession == data[5]`** and the print is exactly the same. Is there any way to achieve this with a flag or something? Excuse my naive question I'm not familiar with python...

```
    fileName = data[6]
    if data[6][0] == '.':
        fileName = data[5] + data[6]
        if not (curIP == data[0] and curDate == data[1] and curAccession == data[5] and curExtention == data[6]):
            print('%s\t%s' % (data[0] + "," + fileName, data[1]))
    else:
        if not (curIP == data[0] and curDate == data[1] and curExtention == data[6]):
            print('%s\t%s' % (data[0] + "," + fileName, data[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I might do it like:

```
fileName = data[6]
match = (curIP, curDate, curExtension) == (data[0], data[1], data[6])
if fileName[0] == '.':
    fileName = data[5] + data[6]
    match &= curAccession == data[5]
if not match:
    print(f"{data[0]},{fileName}\t{data[1]}")
```

Another approach to keeping track of all the different pieces of data that need to match:

```
fileName = data[6]
matches = [(curIP, data[0]), (curDate, data[1]), (curExtension, data[6])]
if fileName[0] == '.':
    fileName = data[5] + data[6]
    matches.append((curAccession, data[5]))
if not all(a == b for a, b in matches):
    print(f"{data[0]},{fileName}\t{data[1]}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the options! They seem interesting concepts, somehow more advanced. My only concern is that I try to avoid storing data like creating tuples and lists because I'm practicing on some big data concepts. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: I'd stick with `match = match and curAccession == data[5]`. If `match` is already `False`, there's no need to evaluate `curAccession == data[5]`. (I don't *think* `&=` will short-circuit, but I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

```py
condition = curIP == data[0] and curDate == data[1] and curExtention == data[6]
if data[6][0] == '.':
    fileName = data[5] + data[6]
    if curAccession != data[5]:
        condition = False
if not condition:
    print('%s\t%s' % (data[0] + "," + fileName, data[1]))
```

The same, but much cleaner, as for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!